# how can i can fix my leaftlat map problems?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a div with id map for leatleft and its only show one tile of map
i really have problem to show full map
please help me

[image]

my css style is

```
#map {
        height: 350px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

and my code is

```
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([35.7336466, 51.3458287], 12);

    L.tileLayer('https://b.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'hello world',
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(mymap);

mymap.locate({
        setView: true,
        maxZoom: 12
    });
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/rLRpmZj49lg1cAU9). Please do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What happens if you resisize your browser window?